# I put my member method and main methods in different files. Illegal start of expression error

Tags: java

I have two java files. 
This application is intended to print facebook personal information as a profile. 
First, is called "driver" which contains the main method and connects to the other file which has member methods in them. 
 I get plenty of illegal start of expression errors.

## Error

```
FacebookLite.java:55: error: illegal start of expression
         private void printFriends(){
         ^
FacebookLite.java:55: error: illegal start of expression
         private void printFriends(){
                 ^
FacebookLite.java:55: error: ';' expected
         private void printFriends(){
                                  ^
FacebookLite.java:67: error: illegal start of expression
         public void printPost(String str){
         ^
FacebookLite.java:67: error: illegal start of expression
         public void printPost(String str){
                ^
FacebookLite.java:67: error: ';' expected
         public void printPost(String str){
                              ^
FacebookLite.java:67: error: ';' expected
         public void printPost(String str){
                                         ^
FacebookLite.java:76: error: illegal start of expression
         public void removeLastPost(){
         ^
FacebookLite.java:76: error: illegal start of expression
         public void removeLastPost(){
                ^
FacebookLite.java:76: error: ';' expected
         public void removeLastPost(){
                                   ^
FacebookLite.java:94: error: illegal start of expression
         public void addFriend(String friend)
         ^
FacebookLite.java:94: error: illegal start of expression
         public void addFriend(String friend)
                ^
FacebookLite.java:94: error: ';' expected
         public void addFriend(String friend)
                              ^
FacebookLite.java:94: error: ';' expected
         public void addFriend(String friend)
                                            ^
FacebookLite.java:100: error: not a statement
               fArr[fIdx].friend;
                         ^
FacebookLite.java:106: error: illegal start of expression
         public void toggleAgeVis(){
         ^
FacebookLite.java:106: error: illegal start of expression
         public void toggleAgeVis(){
                ^
FacebookLite.java:106: error: ';' expected
         public void toggleAgeVis(){
                                 ^
FacebookLite.java:112: error: illegal start of expression
         public void togglefVis(){
         ^
FacebookLite.java:112: error: illegal start of expression
         public void togglefVis(){
                ^
FacebookLite.java:112: error: ';' expected
         public void togglefVis(){
                               ^
FacebookLite.java:118: error: illegal start of expression
         public void togglepVis(){
         ^
FacebookLite.java:118: error: illegal start of expression
         public void togglepVis(){
                ^
FacebookLite.java:118: error: ';' expected
         public void togglepVis(){
                               ^
FacebookLite.java:124: error: illegal start of expression
         public void togglemVis(){
         ^
FacebookLite.java:124: error: illegal start of expression
         public void togglemVis(){
                ^
FacebookLite.java:124: error: ';' expected
         public void togglemVis(){
                               ^
FacebookLite.java:132: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
28 errors
```

## Code

```
class FacebookLite {

//skipped some fields

public FacebookLite(String name, int age) {

  this.name= name;
  this.age = age;
  mood= "";
  fIdx=0;
  fArr= new String[200];
  pIdx=0;
  pArr= new String[200];
  ageVis=true;
  for(int i=0; i<fArr.length; i++)
  {
     fArr[i]="";

     pArr[i]="";

  }

  }
  public void  printProfile()

  {
     if(ageVis)
     {
        System.out.print(age);
     }
  printFriends();
  printPost();

     private void printFriends(){
        int idx=0;
        while(!fArr[idx].equals(""))
        {

           System.out.println(fArr[idx]);
           idx++;
        }

     public void printPost(String str){

        if(pIdx<pArr.length){
           pArr[pIdx]= str;
           pIdx++;
        }
     }
     public void removeLastPost(){

        if(pIdx>0)
        {

           pArr[pIdx-1]="";

           pIdx--;

        }

        else
        {

           System.out.print("sorry no posts to remove");
        }
     }

     public void addFriend(String friend)

     {

        if(fIdx<fArr.length){

           fArr[fIdx].friend;
           fIdx++;
        }

     }
  }

  }
```

Comment: Yes, you're trying to declare your `printFriends()` method within your `printProfile()` method. You can't do that.

Comment: what other ways can i do it?

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please try to reduce it to a [mcve] - you've posted nearly 200 lines of code, very little of which is relevant. Also, format the code - it's horribly unreadable at the moment, with lots of pointless blank lines (e.g. between a method declaration and the opening brace) and the indentation is all fouled up. Format it in your IDE, copy it into Stack Overflow, and press Ctrl-K to indent it all and make it a code block.

Comment: Um, you declare each method separately... I'm not sure I can say much more than that. Put all of your `printProfile()` code in one place, then all of your `printFriends` code...

Comment: should i delete the error section?

Comment: @JonSkeet it's the one time, you're wrong :p He missed closing `}` bracket in two methods in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the closing brackets of method body, Please don't define method into another method body.

See correct code :

```
public class FacebookLite {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String mood;
    private int fIdx;
    private String[] fArr;
    private int pIdx;
    private String[] pArr;
    private boolean ageVis;
    private boolean fVis;
    private boolean pVis;
    private boolean mVis;

    public FacebookLite(String name, int age) {

        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        mood = "";
        fIdx = 0;
        fArr = new String[200];
        pIdx = 0;
        pArr = new String[200];
        ageVis = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < fArr.length; i++) {

            fArr[i] = "";

            pArr[i] = "";

        }

    }

    public void printProfile() {

        if (ageVis) {
            System.out.print(age);
        }

        printFriends();
        printPost("");
    }

    private void printFriends() {

        int idx = 0;

        while (!fArr[idx].equals("")) {

            System.out.println(fArr[idx]);
            idx++;
        }
    }

    public void printPost(String str) {

        if (pIdx < pArr.length) {
            pArr[pIdx] = str;
            pIdx++;
        }
    }

    public void removeLastPost() {

        if (pIdx > 0) {

            pArr[pIdx - 1] = "";

            pIdx--;

        } else {

            System.out.print("sorry no posts to remove");
        }
    }

    public void addFriend(String friend) {

        if (fIdx < fArr.length) {
            String temp = fArr[fIdx];
            fIdx++;
        }

    }

    public void toggleAgeVis() {

        ageVis = !ageVis;

    }

    public void togglefVis() {

        fVis = !fVis;

    }

    public void togglepVis() {

        pVis = !pVis;

    }

    public void togglemVis() {

        mVis = !mVis;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare methods inside other methods. Your class should look like the following:

```
class Foo {
  //fields

  //methods
}
```

Methods can't be nested. You're also missing closing brackets `}`.

In your case, add closing `}` bracket after methods: `printProfile` and `printFriends`. You're also calling `printPost` without argument but it needs a `String`.

#### FacebookLite

```
class FacebookLite {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String mood;
    private int fIdx;
    private String[] fArr;
    private int pIdx;
    private String[] pArr;
    private boolean ageVis;
    private boolean fVis;
    private boolean pVis;
    private boolean mVis;

    public FacebookLite(String name, int age) {

        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        mood = "";
        fIdx = 0;
        fArr = new String[200];
        pIdx = 0;
        pArr = new String[200];
        ageVis = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < fArr.length; i++) {
            fArr[i] = "";
            pArr[i] = "";
        }
    }

    public void printProfile() {
        if (ageVis) {
            System.out.print(age);
        }
        printFriends();
        printPost(); //add something
    }

    private void printFriends() {
        int idx = 0;
        while (!fArr[idx].equals("")) {
            System.out.println(fArr[idx]);
            idx++;
        }
    }

    public void printPost(String str) {
        if (pIdx < pArr.length) {
            pArr[pIdx] = str;
            pIdx++;
        }
    }

    public void removeLastPost() {
        if (pIdx > 0) {
            pArr[pIdx - 1] = "";
            pIdx--;
        } else {
            System.out.print("sorry no posts to remove");
        }
    }

    public void addFriend(String friend) {
        if (fIdx < fArr.length) {
            fArr[fIdx].friend;
            fIdx++;
        }
    }

    public void toggleAgeVis() {
        ageVis = !ageVis;
    }

    public void togglefVis() {
        fVis = !fVis;
    }

    public void togglepVis() {
        pVis = !pVis;
    }

    public void togglemVis() {
        mVis = !mVis;
    }
}
```

Comment: On [so] instead of commenting with a `Thanks` we upvote or mark the answer as a solution.

Comment: I tried but because I'm new here, it doesn't display my vote..I hope it will display soon

Comment: @M.Mir it's one of first priviledges you can earn on [so]. Upvoting. Use it responsibly. If you have some time, read [ask] and [mcve] - it'll help you receive positive votes on your questions

Comment: Cool! Good luck on [so] wishing huge reputation soon! Generally, [help] is very interesting.

Comment: Haha:: Not sure about the huge part yet..But I won't mind having many lol..hope to see u here again!